# Mysql query runs longer than long_query_time variable

Tags: mysql, linux

I have this query in picture attached that runs longer than my long_query_time. Please can anyone recommend what index or indexes to create to speed it up?

Comment: Looks like the query is not displaying at the moment. Could you possibly edit it back in? Just the text is probably better than an image.

Comment: Please provide the query in a machine-readable (text) format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at the query you have you are missing indexes for:

- is_template
- archived
- market_segment
- template_type

I am assuming the indexes you currently have are used for other queries correct?

I am thinking you probably need an index on the other tables name column.

```
ALTER TABLE `projects` ADD INDEX project_ix1( is_template , archived, market_segment, template_type );
ALTER TABLE `template_types` ADD INDEX templatetypes_ix1( alias );
ALTER TABLE `market_segments` ADD INDEX marketsegments_ix1( name );
```

You might want to break up the multi-column index, since this is only for the query you asked about, and I don't know what other queries you might have in the pipe.  Let me know the results.